# Doubts regarding the subtitles in anime and translations in manga

Tags: support, asking-questions

If I have doubts in the subtitles of any anime I watch, regarding the translations, or in the translations of online manga, should I ask it on here or should I ask it on the Japanese language Stack Exchange?

Comment: If you have doubts about the meaning of the words because of what it may mean for the characters or the plot, and you can explain your confusion well enough, post here. If you only want to learn more about the language or how japanese words are used in phrases (linguistic aspects mainly), ask on Japanese.se

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Comment: Consider posting that as an answer, @Hakase ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have doubts about the meaning of the words because of what it may mean for the characters or the plot, and you can explain your confusion well enough, post here. If you only want to learn more about the language or how Japanese words are used in phrases (linguistic aspects mainly), ask on [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/)